# Как отключить UAC при запуске программы через C# (или C++)?

Tags: c#, c++, администрирование, c++-cli, uac

Хочу чтобы программа запустилась от имени администратора без запроса о повышении уровня доступа и без перезапуска Visual Studio от имени админа.
Прога запускается, но требует подтверждения о повышении привилегий. Скорее всего ошибка в том, что я написал блок кода с RegistryKey не в том месте, либо void Main здесь не нужен, либо Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System не универсальный и нужно его менять под себя. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OSotadmina
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey($@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
            key.SetValue("EnableLUA", 0);
            key.SetValue("EnableInstallerDetection", 0);
            key.SetValue("PromptOnSecureDesktop", 0);
            key.SetValue("ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin", 0);
            key.SetValue("EnableSecureUIAPaths", 0);
            key.SetValue("EnableVirtualization", 0);
            key.SetValue("FilterAdministratorToken", 0);
            key.SetValue("EnableUIADesktopToggle", 0);
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Если блок static void Main(string[] args) написать в Program.cs, то ничего не меняется. Всё также выходит окно с запросом подтверждения прав админа.

Comment: вы хотите сделать то, что может сделать только админ, при этом вы не хотите запрашивать админские права? Отключите UAC руками на машине юзера.

Comment: Main здесь не нужен, если вам нужно приложение Winforms, используйте обработчик события `Form.Load` или создайте консольное приложение и используйте там Main. Чтобы программа запрашивала права админа при включенном UAC и без них не запускалась, настройте её manifest. Втихаря обойти UAC не получится, ну или руками его отключить.

Comment: Еще можно при установке или первом запуске приложения создать и зарегистрировать службу с полными правами, и чтобы она всегда работала, а потом просто обращаться к службе. Таким образом получится, что права запросит только в первый раз. Но в этом случае вроде требуется подписывание кода сертификатом.

Comment: Втихую отключать UAC? Подумайте о безопасности пользователей, UAC не просто так включен по умолчанию.

Comment: Хах, я вас понял) Думал вдруг есть какие-то идеи как это все же можно сделать, даже если пришлось бы писать огромный код с заковырками. Видимо это невозможно, окей. Всем спасибо :)

Comment: А если сделать так чтобы только моя программа запускалась без запроса UAC от имени админа? То есть я сам в манифесте указываю, что для запуска необходимо обладать правами администратора и потом при запуске меня спрашивают о согласии на повышение привилегий с перезапуском Visual Studio. Можно как-то сделать чтоб хотя бы в этом случае не было такого запроса?

Comment: @llatibro Запуск под админом в любом случае выводит окно запроса если UAC включено. Как вариант - делать сервис который будет запускаться под админом, а с сервисом общаться программой запускаемой под обычным пользователем.